# Redesigning the Arduino Duemilanove and Ethernet shield in to a single board

Tags: arduino

I have build a prototype with the Arduino Duemilanove and a Ethernet shield. It works great, now I want to get it redesigned in to a single board with a few extra connectors.

- Screw terminal for power,
- Screw terminal for a few of the digital pins,
- RS232 connection to the serial port.
- RJ-45 port
- I also want an enclosure for this new board.

**Q: Why do I want to redesign the board?**
I can't have a barrel connector for power, its a requirement from the site where I want to install this product. I also want a nice metal enclosure ( I couldn't find one for the Arduino that was reasonably priced.

**Q: How many units would you be making**
100-250 to start and more as time goes on.

My question is; Where should I post this job posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try one of the freelance design sites like [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com/projects/by-job/PCB-Layout.html). You need to take into account the cost of EMC conformity in the country where you live; CE conformance is required in the EU, and can be quite expensive- something like £3,000 in the UK for that sort of item.

Comment: I realize that there will be a high initial cost, as long as there is a low per unit cost its OK. Freelancer website seems to be what I am looking for, thanks. Now I just need to think of an appropriate price tag.

Answer (score 0):

have you found a soution for that ?

I would be verry interested in something simillar for automating my home :)

any chanches of releasing the design to the community? maybe to the official arduino hardware page ...

thanks,

alex

Comment: We ended up going an entirely different route, so we could get CU/CL approval stickers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just get a bulk deal on these:
http://www.freetronics.com/products/etherten

Comment: He specifically said he can't have a barrel jack for power.