# DIN rail enclosure for a Arduino + Ethernet shield

Tags: arduino, enclosure

I am looking for a way to put a Arduino with an Ethernet shield inside a DIN rail enclosure while exposing the RJ45 and a few screw terminals.

Bare min: 55mm Width, 75mm length, 30mm height. 
Looks similar this http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Guide/ArduinoWithEthernetShield.jpg

Parts list:

- http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9026 sitting on top of
- http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=666

The problem we are having is how to expose the RJ45 connector.

We were thinking of finding an enclosure that supports a RJ45 Keystone and running wires from the board to the exposed terminals but we haven't found anything like that yet.

We where also thinking about getting the two boards [redesigned in to a single board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/redesigning-the-arduino-duemilanove-and-ethernet-shield-in-to-a-single-board) that fits a existing enclosure. But that would cost 1000s of dolors. Or at lest thats what I been quoted.

I been searching and phoning people for about a week without finding an answer. I'm  looking for suggestions, hints, wild guess, anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could design and build your own with laser cut panels. This guy's arduino and shield look the same as yours.

http://www.iheartrobotics.com/search/label/A%20Case

http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/03/case-for-arduino-laser-cutouts.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+IHeartRobotics+%28I+Heart+Robotics%29

http://www.shapeways.com/model/85671/arduino_case.html

Answer (score 2):

There are variety of blank DIN enclosures. Are you saying you
couldn't find one large enough for the combination of boards?

For a feedthru connector something like the Neutrik NE8FDP 
should work. You just need to drill three round holes.

For a professional to design, prototype and document a single
board it would probably be in the $2K-$3K range.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for mentioning the Arduino Case project.

In the next week or so the design should be finalized for the injection molded version.
After that we are going to have pre-orders available via Kickstarter.

The goal of the project is to produce a case for Arduino project that can hold a shield and can support 80% of the projects people are working on.

If you have suggestions or changes you would like to see, let us know sooner rather than later.

Answer (score -1):

you could try this, but I'm not sure if it works with a shield on top or not ...

https://www.hunter-automaton.com/ProductPage.aspx?prod=1000

Answer (score -1):

I just asked to seeedstudio to build something like that
    http://www.seeedstudio.com/wish/?p=939

please vote it if still interested, or in case you found a solution, please let me know...